# Python SQLite3 fails on Github Actions but not on local

Tags: python, sqlite, github-actions

I'm setting up CI using Github Actions and SQLite3 it's failing to insert on Github Actions but not on a local machine.

The line that fails is:

`conn.execute("INSERT INTO sessions VALUES (?, ?, FALSE, NULL, ?)", [new_auth_token, device_id, expire_date])`

This line is executed a few times in diferent tests succesfully, but then it fails in the rest of the tests (Always the same tests fail) with the next error.

`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: FALSE`

I'm using python3.8 and I've tried it on my computer with a fresh install of python and clone of the repository, but it never fails locally, only on GithuActions.

Comment: Try using QueryBuilder.substitutions to generate booleans, that will probably fix it.

Comment: What does your workflow file look like? What does your test setup look like?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

What fixed the problem for me is in my YAML workflow, replacing

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

with

```
runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
```

ubuntu-latest uses Ubuntu 18.04 and the SQLite version seems to be old and have an issue.